# NSCalendar return wrong date for previous Monday in first week of next year

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using below code to calculate previous Monday using random date. Which work file but my code break on next year date.below is the code for same :

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1483620311.228];
NSLog(@"current date ===> : %@", date);

NSCalendar *calendar;
calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[calendar setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-US"]];
NSTimeZone *zone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Sydney"];
[calendar setTimeZone:zone];

NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond | NSCalendarUnitTimeZone fromDate:date];
if (nowComponents.weekday == 1) {    //If my date fall in sunday then I am moving to previous week.
    [nowComponents setWeekOfYear:[nowComponents weekOfYear]-1];
}

[nowComponents setWeekday:2]; //Monday

NSDate *previousMonday = [calendar dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
NSLog(@"previousMonday date ===> : %@", previousMonday);
```

In Log I am getting as  :

> current date ===> : 2017-01-05 12:45:11 +0000
>   previousMonday date ===> : 2018-01-01 12:45:11 +0000

I have seen other stack overflow resource but not getting expected solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a much smarter way to do that using `nextDateAfterDate` of `NSCalendar`. It can search backwards for the match of a single component in this case `NSCalendarUnitWeekday == 2`

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1483620311.228]; 
NSLog(@"current date ===> : %@", date);
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDate *previousMonday = [calendar nextDateAfterDate:date 
                                        matchingUnit:NSCalendarUnitWeekday  
                                               value:2 
                                             options:NSCalendarMatchNextTime | NSCalendarSearchBackwards];
NSLog(@"previousMonday date ===> : %@", previousMonday);
```

The time zone and locale don't really matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It work for me. do you have any idea why my code is printing wrong value?

Comment: I have to change my question title to make this an answer. because it does not match with question title.

Comment: The error occurs only if the locale is set to `en_US`. I regard this as a bug.